# Flutter: ImagePicker UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation Exception

Tags: ios, flutter, exception, imagepicker

I'm using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and running into the error below on an iPad running iOS 10.4 when I execute this call `ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)` on an app with a landscape (both left and right) orientation only.

This works fine on an iOS simulator running 14+.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1cef7b3d 0x1c17f067 0x1cef7a85 0x221960b9 0x2219ee67 0x2219ee07 0x2219d427 0x22120aeb 0x221208a9 0x221208a9 0x221208a9 0x2211fee5 0x2211fd71 0x2212b27f 0x2212ac03 0x22218757 0x22217b3f 0x2245cc43 0x223a2983 0x22395c93 0x221178bd 0x1ceb3803 0x1ceb1a55 0x1ceb2017 0x1ce051af 0x1ce04fd1 0x1e5afb41 0x22187a53 0xbe7f7 0x1c5f24eb)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I do specify the app orientation using the following command, but I find that the error happens regardless of whether this is used or not.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight])
  .then((_){
    runApp(MyApp());
  }
);
```

The corresponding device orientations are selected in my `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

[image]

### Update 1:

When using the camera, with the following command, the picker works fine on iOS 10.4.

```
ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `Info.plist` must have the `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` item in the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` array.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

(In my instance I had to add it to the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iPad` array too.)